# interpolation method for google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, statistics, kml

I wanted to ask you about the way to make spatial interpolation in google maps API. This means- I have values for some points inside an area and want to recalculate values for every point in this area (and create an raster overlay).
In "offline" GIS softwares, there are more methods to do this. For example Kriging (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging).

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real practical way to do such a thing. Spatial Interpolation is something you really need a full-blown GIS to accomplish. It requires storing, analyzing, and presenting data in way that ArcGis or QGis is best suited for. There is some new feature in ArcGis Online that works with Google Maps API but I don't know much about it and am unsure if it would be any help for you but a link is [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/gmaps/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for answer .But that means: i have to convert my spreadsheet data to .kml (then to .shp), then load them with QuantumGIS (or ArcMap,...), make analyse, export as a raster and add overlay to google map everytime I want to refresh my data ?

Comment: Yeah. thats what a GIS is for. The google Maps API is nice and all but not really a favorite in the statisticians toolbox.

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this with the google maps api anyway? Maybe there is a better soultion outside of that api?

Comment: I was about to make dynamically generated dasymetric map. I found library to make this with heatmap ([link](http://code.google.com/p/tikouka/source/browse/trunk/tikouka-appengine/js/heatmap-gmaps.js?spec=svn71&r=71),...) and was wondering, if its also possible with interpolation. Anyway, thank you for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know, its not something geostatiscically correct, but I have made this:
- I have created a net of rectangle polygons. 
- I have connected all my points to polygon they lie and have made mean value for polygons with at least one point
- I have checked every polygon without points and at least 2 neighbourly polygons with points, and have made mean from this neighbourly values
- I have checked again all my polygons with values and at least 2 neighbourly polygons with values and smoothed origin values according to the neighbours´ values.

Comment: Hello Eidam!
Your idea would match my need perfectly. Is there an example of how you did it?